# how to make redux API share cache with all endpoints?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am learning redux and I am facing a challenge in my practice projects. here, I have a usersList page which fetches all the users with getUsers query. when I click each user, I visit the user profile page. when I first visit the usersList page, I already fetch every user's data, so when I visit the profile page, there really shouldn't be anypoint in calling the server again, but here, when I visit the profile page of each user after visiting users list, it still calls the server and creates another cache in the redux. this leads to an unnessesary api call which I want to avoid.

as you can see in the image I provided, redux create a cache getUsers("userid") and also getSingleUser("userid"), how can I make it so that these to become one?

what is senior devs approuch to avoid this unnesssary api call? is there another way to get around this issue?

[image]

here is my endpoints for users:

```
import { apiSlice } from "../apiSlice";

const userApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getUsers: builder.query ({
      query: () => 'user',
      providesTags: (result, error, context) => {
        if (!error && result) {
          return [{type: 'User', id: 'LIST'}, ...result.users.map(user => ({type: 'User', id: user._id}))]
        } else {
          return [{type: 'User', id: 'LIST'}]
        }
      }
    }),
    getSingleUser: builder.query ({
      query: (id) => `user/${id}`,
      providesTags: (result, error, context) => {
        if (result && !error) {
          return [{type: 'User', id: result.user._id}]
        }
      }
    }),
    getUserBySearch: builder.query ({
      query: (search = '') => `user/search?q=${search}`,
      providesTags: (result, error, context) => {
        if (!error && result) {
          return [{type: 'User', id: 'LIST'}, ...result.users.map(user => ({type: 'User', id: user._id}))]
        } else {
          return [{type: 'User', id: 'LIST'}]
        }
      },
      keepUnusedDataFor: 5,
    }),
    createUser: builder.mutation({
      query: (credentials) => ({
        url: 'user',
        method: 'POST',
        body: credentials,
      }),
      invalidatesTags: [{type: 'User', id: 'LIST'}]
    }),
    deleteUser: builder.mutation ({
      query: (id) => ({
        url: `user/${id}`,
        method: 'DELETE'
      }),
      invalidatesTags: (result, error, context) => {
        console.log(`this is result: ${JSON.stringify(result)}`)
        if (result?.id && !error) {
          return [{type: 'User', id: result.id}]
        }
      }
    })
  })
})

export const {
  useGetUsersQuery,
  useGetSingleUserQuery,
  useGetUserBySearchQuery,
  useCreateUserMutation,
  useDeleteUserMutation
} = userApiSlice;
```

I expect to user the recourses from getUsers when I vist a user's profile page instead of calling the api again